# Clicking on switch does not change state the first time only if it's checked already

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a newbie in React and just started to develop an admin panel on local to practice what I have learned and I have come across this problem and after searching for a long while and being unable to solve it I'm this close to step on kittens and innocent children ...

so here's the situation:

I have a panel for registering some products, say, Shoes and on my Dashboard page of admin panel I have my products listed and I can click on edit on any of them to redirect to edit page and change the info like name, price, image etc.

Up to this point everything works as intended, the problem is I have a Switch Input which indicates if it's a featured product or not and when I land on the edit page it displays correctly if it's On or Off, now when I click on it to change its state, the first time I click nothing happens and it starts working after 2nd click onwards.

I've done my research and came to know it has to do with using useEffect() and such and I've changed my code accordingly and now the real problem is when the switch is off when I land on edit page, on first click it works just fine and it changes to On and I can save it and it'll do as intended but if it's On by default when I land on the edit page, the first click won't work and it takes 2 click and more to change the state and it escapes me how it works fine when it's off and not both ways.

p.s it's my first time asking question here so I might have failed to express my problem clearly or properly enough so my apologies in advance.

Here's the code:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import getOneProduct from "../../../Services/getOneProduct";
import {useProductsDispatch} from "../../../Context/productsContext";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";

function EditProductForm() {

    const dispatch = useProductsDispatch()

    const redirect = useNavigate()
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({
        name: '',
        desc: '',
        price: '',
        offPrice: '',
        image: '',
        feat: null,
        uid: '',
        date: '',
    })

    const [switchVal, setSwitchVal] = useState(); // this is the state I use for the switch but would rather have it in the 'product' state above so they are all together

    const switchHandler = (e) => { // the onChange function for the switch
        const curVal = e.target.checked
        setSwitchVal(curVal)
    }

    useEffect(() => { // the useEffect to reflect switch changes
        setProduct({
            ...product,
            feat: switchVal
        })
        console.log(switchVal)
    }, [switchVal, setSwitchVal]);

    const changeHandler = (e) => { // the input handler for all other inputs
        setProduct({
            ...product,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    const editProductSubmit = (e) => { // form onSubmit
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch({
            type: 'EDIT_PRODUCT',
            payload: {
                productId,
                product
            }
        })
        redirect("/admin/dashboard")
    }
    const fetchedId = useParams()
    const productId = fetchedId.id
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchedProduct = async () => {
            try {
                const {data} = await getOneProduct(productId) // axios.get()
                setProduct({
                    name: data.name,
                    desc: data.desc,
                    price: data.price,
                    offPrice: data.offPrice,
                    image: data.image,
                    feat: data.feat,
                    uid: data.uid,
                    date: data.date,
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        fetchedProduct()
    }, [productId])

    return (
        <div>
            <form className="add-product-form" onSubmit={editProductSubmit}>
                <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                        defaultValue={product.name}
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="productName"
                        name="name"
                        placeholder="نام محصول"
                    />
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="productName">نام محصول</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <textarea
                        defaultValue={product.desc}
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        className="form-control"
                        id="productDesc"
                        name="desc"
                        placeholder="Leave a comment here"
                        style={{height: 200}}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="productDesc">توضیحات محصول</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                        defaultValue={product.price}
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        type="number"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="productPrice"
                        name="price"
                        placeholder="قیمت اصلی محصول"
                    />
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="productPrice">قیمت اصلی محصول</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                        defaultValue={product.offPrice}
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        type="number"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="productOffPrice"
                        name="offPrice"
                        placeholder="قیمت با تخفیف محصول"
                    />
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="productOffPrice">قیمت با تخفیف محصول</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                        defaultValue={product.image}
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="productImage"
                        name="image"
                        placeholder="لینک تصویر محصول"
                    />
                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="productImage">لینک تصویر محصول</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-switch form-check-reverse mb-3">
                    <input
                        onChange={switchHandler}
                        defaultChecked={product.feat}
                        value={switchVal}
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="form-check-input"
                        id="productFeat"
                        role="switch"
                    /> {/* This is the switch in question */}
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="productFeat">محصول ویژه است</label>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">ویرایش محصول</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default EditProductForm;
```

Comment: It's all come to this line feat: null, which is the default value, try replace null by either true or false.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well I'm trying to populate the input values of the edit form with actual values from this certain product hence I want the switch to be on if its value from time of creatin is on and likewise if it's off. if I set the default value to true for example it works but then any product I try to edit will have the switch On on the page load and it's not working for me since I want it to be set accordingly to it's state.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `const [switchVal, setSwitchVal] = useState();` to `const [switchVal, setSwitchVal] = useState(false);` it will have a starting value of false instead of undefined. Assuming the box has to be unchecked on rendering. Just change it to `true` if you need it to be true on render.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the value of the switch is determined by the state of the product when it was created so it might be true or false depending on the product. with this being said, could I still set it to false or true as the initial value ? can initial value be set by the product.feat value of state which indicates if it should be on or off ?

Comment: As @Sebastian Gudiño commented, you should probably set the conditional value as your initial switch state to make this work.